# Login fails with innocent looking code in a sourced script on openSUSE

Tags: bash, authentication, opensuse

I have a number of bash scripts that load during login, to provide helpful functions that other scripts I run rely on.

I have recently moved to OpenSUSE Tumbleweed from MacOS, and Linux will not login with this code present in one of my sourced scripts.

```
while (( $# >= 1 )); do
    case ${1} in
        'ERR')      ___NOERR___=0;   ___hsUtilitiesForceReload__=1;;
        'EXIT')     ___NOEXIT___=0;  ___hsUtilitiesForceReload__=1;;
        'INT')      ___NOINT___=0;   ___hsUtilitiesForceReload__=1;;
        'WINCH')    ___NOWINCH___=0; ___hsUtilitiesForceReload__=1;;
        'FORCE')                     ___hsUtilitiesForceReload__=1;;
        'QUIET')    ___QUIET___=1;;
        *)          printf "Command line parameter not understood: \"%s\"" "${1}";;
    esac
    shift
done
```

With this commented out, the login is successful, but with it in place, login fails and I get returned to the login screen.

If I test this apart from login, it seems to be fine. I have tested it by entering

```
set -eu
source [...path...]/utilities.sh
set +eu
```

and the script loads without error.

Can anybody guess what may be going on?
TIA

Comment: If the script you posted is indeed the complete `utilities.sh`, the case is interesting. I see that you invoke the script without arguments, which in turn means that `$#` is zero. The `while` loop is therefore skipped, so the only thing which could kill you is the `set -e`. However this should not happen, because i.e. `while false; do :; done` sets exit status zero. For getting more insight into the problem, I would first remove the `set -e` (which IMO does not make much sense here anyway), and do instead a `set -x`, so that you can see at which point it bails out.

Comment: It's not the entire utilities.sh, but with those lines commented out I can log in, but if the lines are active, login fails. So it seems to me that those lines are causing the problem. The 2nd snippet is my test jig, those commands are entered at the command line. In .bashrc I simply have the "source" line.

Comment: Also, if I make an error in typing or a command returns non zero, my terminal session is ended abruptly, as if some ERR trap is being executed, but I don't have anything like that. All this code runs without any problem on MacOS.

Comment: Please add output from `bash --version` for both environments. Good luck.

Comment: Per  user1934428 's insightful comment. Please test with a typical argument provided to `./utillities.sh` . I recommend `set -vx` (`set -x` is ind too), instead of `set -e`. Alos your "termnial session clossing unexpectedly" may be unrelated. This behavior is typical of source'd functions (from the cmd line) where there is an `exit` command that turns up in-scope (that is to say, if it is conditionally controlled, then `if-then` has fired. Good luck.

Comment: You need to go back to the MacOS to see what it was providing that script at time of execution for it to respond as you expected on MacOS.  Then you will know the conditions that need to be replicated in Linux for that script to operate as you expect.  Obviously, the script WAS getting a value passed as a command line parameter in the MacOS environment.  Otherwise, it would never have worked.

Comment: Look for the `exit` in that script, and change it to `return`. That is the only reason that comes to mind why is the terminal is exiting/closing. Also `set -e` on a dotfiles?

Comment: @Jetchisel : While an `exit` indeed would be bad, I don't see one in the code the OP has posted.

Comment: > _So it seems to me that those lines are causing the problem_. This is not something which needs to **seem**, but which you can **know** by running the script with `set -x` turned on, as this will show you exactly the failing point. Why doing guesswork, if you can get the exact information for free?

Comment: `exit() { printf 'Would have exited with %s\n' "${1:-0}"; }`, Should print the message to `stdout` instead of exiting/quitting the terminal/login, if indeed `exit` is being triggered/executed.

Comment: @user1934428, until the OP posted the complete script, yeah all of this is just a guessing game.

Comment: Thanks for everybody's help here, it happens there WAS an TRAP set in one of the files sourced. I was preparing a minimal example to show you the entire thing when I found it.